# PHPBB with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpbb3

How to integrate phpbb with a wordpress site. When ever a user registered on my site automatically creates a forum account also. Any body knows the solution for this please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check [WP-UNITED](http://www.wp-united.com/)

> WP-United glues together phpBB forums
>   and WordPress blogs.
>
> From simple single sign-on, to fully
>   automatic template integrations,
>   WP-United can help you create a
>   fully-featured, compelling community
>   site.

Comment: WP-United is dead. If you look at the developer's Twitter stream it almost seems like he got kidnapped in Japan a year ago. Lots of activity, then a tweet about landing in an airport in japan, and then dead silence ever since. Not a peep that I can find. Also, the site just says "Black Magic Dev ;)" and is completely devoid of content otherwise. WP-phpBB-Bridge is the only thing I've found that comes close to being a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the WP phpBB Bridge to syncronize user login for both WordPress and phpBB. You can find more info here : [WP phpBB Bridge](http://www.e-xtnd.it/wp-phpbb-bridge/)

Comment: In a few days a new version will be available. We Move on 2.0.0.

Comment: This plugin has some not insignificant issues. Like, flushing permalinks on every page load. Haven't found a better one yet though. @Merianos Nikos Are you going to be updating it further and ironing out some more of these bugs?